# String or Binary Data Would be Truncated…

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my project I am generating a random character using the Random Number generator function and Storing it in the database, the number generates correctly but during insert of the data it is throwing the Exception **“String or binary data would be truncated”**

My code:

```
protected void trigger()
{  
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = ExamManagement.SP.table2_SP_Selectall().GetDataSet();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string a = RandomNumberGenerator(4);
            string b = RandomNumberGenerator(4);
            string c = RandomNumberGenerator(4);
            ExamManagement.SP.table1_insert(a,b,c).Execute();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        ClientMessaging("Error :"+ex);
    }
}

public static string RandomNumberGenerator(int length)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator rng = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

    char[] chars = new char[length];

    //based on your requirment you can take only alphabets or number 
    string validChars = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXzZ";
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length-1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {

        rng.GetBytes(bytes);

        Random rnd = new Random(bytes[0]);

        chars[i] = validChars[rnd.Next(validChars.Length)];

    }

    return (new string(chars));
}
```

My SQL Server Table Structure:

```
  Column1, nvarchar(100),null
  Column2, nvarchar(100),null
  Column3, nvarchar(100),null
```

My Altered Stored Procedure is,

```
   Create Procedure Table1_insert    
   (    
    @col1 varchar(max),    
    @col2 varchar(max),    
    @col3 varchar(max)   
   )    
  as    
 BEGIN    
 BEGIN TRY    
 Insert into Table1(Column1,Column2,Column3) values (@col1,@col2,@col3)    
END TRY    
BEGIN CATCH                    
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0                    
ROLLBACK                    
DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int                    
SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),                    
@ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()                    
RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)                    
END CATCH     
END
```

Comment: This message means that the content you want to fill in your column does not fit. So you probably have more then 100 chars in one of your columns. Count your variable and output it before you insert it in your database to see.

Comment: @Yvesr I had checked it with Clientmessaging, the Randomnumbergenerator Function generates only Four Characters eg: sDfT

Comment: isn't it obvious that the data is bigger than the field length?

Comment: Try to use a `SQL Profiler` and see the actual value which is getting inserted into the table

Comment: @praveen  I don't have 'SQL Profiler' because The SQL Server installed in my system is SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Rajesh did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Column Variable Present in the DB is Smaller in Size than the Variable Data I have Sent to save So I got the Error **String or binary data would be truncated**

I had solved the error by Increasing the size of the Variable in DB

Answer (score 0):

Check your stored proc. You probably forgot to specify the length on your parameters. Eg. @p1 nvarchar(1000)

Comment: The parameters Specified in my SP is **.@col1 nvarchar(100), .@col2 nvarchar(100), .@col3 nvarchar(100)**

Comment: How about the specification of the table1_insert method. Did you use a designer to create the method? You might want to check the parameter mappings. If you forget to specify the length sql server will asume one character.

Comment: I had edited my Post with the Stored Procedure kindly see it and give me solution.....

Comment: I wasn't after your stored proc but rather after the code of             ExamManagement.SP.table1_insert(a,b,c).